# ASP.Net ImageButton: How to hide the red cross when no ImageUrl is present and just show the AlternateText

Tags: asp.net

I have an Imagebutton with an empty ImageUrl but there is some text in the AlternateText. In IE, it is displayed with a red cross and the alternatetext next to the red cross. In FF, only the alternatetext appears with no red cross image and that is what I want. Plz, I need to work with Imagebutton...dont suggest replacing it with linkbutton or anything else.
So how can I get rid of the red cross thing in IE.

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I did two images for the Image button with the alternate Text as the text inside the images. One image had an underline for the text. Added mouseover and mouseout events where  the src of the images changes. So it appears as a link.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the questionable scenario of *having* to work with the `ImageButton`, the only solution I see is creating a transparent 1x1 gif and assign this URL instead of an empty URL in case no image should be displayed, but the alt text still shown.

That said, if you are after the tooltip text I'd strongly recommend using a `div` or an other suitable element with the `title` attribute set instead.

Comment: I have a click event for this image button..If i replace it with 1x1 size image, then the user wont be able to click the image and the event will never fire...